# Buttons are moving in different directions after resizing

Tags: html, css, button

So I've created 2 buttons and they are in wrapper and putted on image.
Problem occurs when I'm resizing the window, they just start moving in different directions, my question is how to prevent this?

Comment: Heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j7yLwb8u/

Comment: can you improve you jsfiddle code fist? we don't understand you question.

Comment: How to prevent the moving buttons when I'm resizing the window.

Comment: i still don't get it, i guess it's the `position: absolute` causes the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a typo in your css where you have `left:390`.

Replace this:

```
.btn-cta {
  top:40%;
  left:390;
  position: absolute;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

By this:

```
.btn-cta {
  top:40%;
  left:390px;
  position: absolute;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

Does this solve your issue?